# Sharing resources between two classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have provided a working example where I have a dynamic array implemented as custom type in Python 3. I wish to use a single instance of this dynamic array as a common resource for implementing, say, `N` stacks. How do I do that?

I imagine I would like to give each stack an access to only a certain part of the `DynamicArray` by making demarcation points `_start` and `_end`. In order to have `_start` and `_end` for each stack, I would like to wrap them in a helper class `_StackRecord`. In case I am successful in providing a modifiable view of `DynamicArray`, I want `_StackRecord` to do all the heavy lifting of poping and pushing such that the stacks don't collide while the underlying `DynamicArray` expands/shrinks as per the need. I know I am asking for too much, but I might learn some useless skills while I fail to do this.

Any suggestions/criticism towards modularity, maintainability and good practices are wholeheartedly welcome.

```py
import ctypes

class DynamicArray:
    """Expandable array class similar to Python list"""
    def __init__(self, size=0):
        self._n        = size
        self._capacity = size + 1
        self._A        = self._make_low_level_array(self._capacity)
        
    def _make_low_level_array(self, capacity):
        return (capacity*ctypes.py_object)()
    
    # following two methods are needed for Python to implement __iter__
    def __len__(self):
        return self._n
    
    def __getitem__(self, index_key):
        if isinstance(index_key, slice):
            start, stop, step = index_key.indices(len(self))
            return [self._A[i] for i in range(start, stop, step)]
        elif isinstance(index_key, int):
            if 0 <= index_key < self._n :
                return self._A[index_key]
            else:
                raise IndexError("index out of bounds")
        elif isinstance(index_key, tuple):
            raise NotImplementedError('Tuple as index')
        else:
            raise TypeError('Invalid argument type: {}'.format(type(key)))
         
    def __setitem__(self, index_k, value):
        if 0 <= index_k < self._n :
            self._A[index_k] = value
        else:
            raise IndexError("index out of bounds")
    ###################################################################        
    
class FixedMultiStack:
    class _StackRecord(DynamicArray):
        def __init__(self, array: DynamicArray, stack_number=0, size_of_each=10):
            self._stack = stack_number
            self._start = stack_number*size_of_each
            self._end   = self._start + size_of_each
            # try commenting the following lines
            self._n     = size_of_each
            self._A     = DynamicArray(self._n)
            # If I have to use self._A then I would like it to point 
            # to array[self._start:self._end]
            for i in range(self._start, self._end):
                array[i]   = i
            for i in range(self._n):
                self._A[i] = array[self._start+ i]

    def __init__(self, numStack=1, sizeEach=10):
        self._stacks = []
        self._items  = DynamicArray(numStack*sizeEach)
        
        for i in range(numStack):
            self._stacks.append(self._StackRecord(self._items, i, sizeEach))
            
    def __getitem__(self, stack_number):
        return self._stacks[stack_number]
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fms = FixedMultiStack(3,10)
    print(list(fms[0]))
    print(list(fms[1]))
    print(list(fms[2]))
    print(list(fms._items))
```

## Issues

I am doing the wasteful act of making a local copy called `self._A`. How do I avoid that? Why can't I just work on the global dynamic array passed to my local record keeper `_StackRecord`?

## What do I expect?

1. `fms = FixedMultiStack(3,10)`, A fixed multi stack packing 3 stacks of size 10 each such that
2. I would like, if `self._A` is necessary, the local `self._A` to refer to that part of `DynamicArray` which corresponds to the given stack number.
3. So that `print(list(fms[n]))` gives me the contents of nth stack
4. While `print(list(fms._items))` should give me the combine state of all the stacks. Yikes! `print(list(fms._items))` is ugly. How about `print(list(fms))`?
5. I should be able to write something like `self._items[n].push(val)`, `self._items[n].pop()` to push and pop on n-th stack.

Comment: "# following two methods are needed for Python to implement __iter__
    def __len__(self):" Note, this is totally wrong. They aren't *needed*. You *could* implement `__iter__` directly, although, the "old", sequence based iteration protocol will use `__getitem__` and `__len__`, but probably you should provide an explicit `__iter__` in code you write today

Comment: Hey @juanpa.arrivillaga, I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out. By the way, "old" as in Py 2.2x?

Comment: Actually the old protocol does not even use len. It tries __getitem__ until an IndexErrror is raised

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I had a minimal reproducible example to begin with. Maybe you didn't try to run the above program for yourself.

Comment: It's really hard to discern what you are asking. You `_StackRecord` inherits from `DynamicArray`, and you try to use `_StackRecord` like an array, so *of course* it needs `self._n` and `self._A`, how else could it work? I have no idea what you mean by 
"If I have to use self._A then I would like it to point to array[self._start:self._end]". There's **tons** of excess here, you have several classes, you could probably reproduce the problem with a single class, or two. Stop using nested  classes, it makes your code difficult to read (for people used to reading Python)

Comment: What do you mean you "repeat the declaration of self._n and self._A in '_StackRecord'" You don't repeat anything at all. Note, *python doesn't have variable declarations*, so you simply assign to `self._n` and `self._A`, which you must since the rest of your implementation relies on those attributes...

Comment: "I am doing the wasteful act of making a local copy called self._A. How do I avoid that? Why can't I just work on the global dynamic array passed to my local record keeper '_StackRecord'." **what global array**? You aren't working with any global arrays. You try to create an instance of `_StackRecord`, passing it an instance of a `DynamicArray`. I *think* you want to create some sort of *view* over the `DynamicArray` contents, so you don't have to copy, but it's very hard to understand your intention

Comment: Generally, you woudl just have a single DynamicArray for a multi-stack. You essentially have to keep track of whether the stacks interfere with each other in the array and then re-arrange the array when they do. Your `_StackRecord` class seems unecessary to me, at least, if it is, it shouldn't inherit from `DynamicArray`. Keeping a python list that has various stacks really defeats the purpose of the exercise

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga All of these are fair suggestions/criticisms and I would do the appropriate edits in the main post to make my intention clear. Still I would put down here few things,
1. I am using `DynamicArray` as a base class for designing Stacks and Queues. I know that's a horrible idea. Still, I am doing it to learn class construction and inheritance in Python.
2. TIL,  python doesn't have variable declarations.
3. Thousand times yes, I want to create some sort of view over the `DynamicArray`
4. I am stuck at this point how to achieve #3 and your suggestion in the last comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) for creating the different views over the entire array:

```
class FixedMultiStack:
    def __init__(self, m, n):
        self.data = bytearray(m*n)
        view = memoryview(self.data)
        self.stacks = [view[i*n:(i+1)*n] for i in range(m)]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.stacks[index]
```

Comment: I will need some time to understand and implement this. Just over the surface, does this mean I don't need `_StackRecord` and `DynamicArray`? If not, i.e. if I can still use `DynamicArray` then how do I check if it supports the buffer protocol?

Comment: @Sowmya I'm not sure what the purpose of your `DynamicArray` is but for storing data the [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module offers plenty of options. The [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) is a rather low level interface, hence not suitable for high level classes.